# Question hammered closed by community

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, community

Today, I noticed two questions being hammered closed by “community;” here is one example: [How can I appropriately call my professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/166472/how-can-i-appropriately-call-my-professor). While both questions might have been candidates for closure for the reasons given, I am wondering if this is something I just missed seeing in my years on stackexchange, or a new feature (e.g., using ML to find likely candidates for closure). If it’s an algorithm, I find it a bit risky as false positives will happen, and re-opening a good question is harder than closing a bad one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Bryan's answer [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4844/79875). In short: the vote by community user indicates that OP agreed their question was a duplicate. You can see this by mousing over "community" in the question's timeline.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: If the OP closed it themselves, shouldn't the interface say "closed XX days ago by <authorname>" rather than "closed XX days ago by Community", though? This would be clearer and more factually accurate.

Comment: Yes, it would be clearer. The rationale behind the current message (which we as Academia.SE cannot change) is that OP cannot actually close their own post; rather, their vote to close triggers the AutoMod, which mod hammers it closed. "Community" is the name of the AutoMod.